# Visual Studio 2010, jump to source code using IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, solution

Let me break down my problem. I have two visual studio 2010 solutions with multiple projects in them.

```
Solution A
Solution B
```

`Solution A` generates libs that are added as dependency in `Solution B`.
This way i first have to compile Solution A and then Solution B. This process is also part of an automated build environment so i don't want to change this.

**Problem**:

While coding, i am calling a procedure in Solution A project which goes into lib of Solution B. I can see the header file while jumping from source code using visual studio of Solution A. But when i try to go to definition of header file function (for example), it can not do that.

So I have to separately open solution B and jump to the relevant files. Is there a possibility to be able to jump to source code without merging the two solutions together?

Comment: anyone? any ideas?